# Correcting the error encountered while migrating a Spring Boot application from JDK 8 to JDK 17

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, java-17

When I ported my project from Java 8 to Java 17, I encountered the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userPreferencesDAO': Error creating bean with name 'userPreferencesDAO' defined in com.thetisit.felayer.repository.UserPreferencesDAO defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.thetisit.felayer.entity.UserPreferences
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at com.thetisit.SecuredUsersFELayer.main(SecuredUsersFELayer.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userPreferencesDAO' defined in com.thetisit.felayer.repository.UserPreferencesDAO defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.thetisit.felayer.entity.UserPreferences
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.thetisit.felayer.entity.UserPreferences
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Here is the entry class in the application:

```java
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SecuredUsersFELayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SecuredUsersFELayer.class, args);
    }
}
```

My entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS_PREFERENCES")
public class UserPreferences {

    @Id
    private String username;

    private String preferences;
    
    // getters and setters
    .
    .
    .
}
```

In the pom.xml file, I have the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency:

The parent of my project is `spring-boot-starter-data` migrating from version 2.4.1 to 3.1.0.

Comment: 1. Did you mean spring-boot-starter-parent? 2. Your entity needs the no arguments constructor. 3. ConfigurationPropertiesScan annotation not needed.

Comment: 4. Please also show the userPreferencesDAO class where the error occurs. 5. Rename the javax packages in the import statements to jakarta (as posted in the answer).

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. Anyway, as Pgt7 said, the problem was that I used the wrong package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem, completely but I guess the problem is in the dependencies. Make sure the libraries and dependencies are OK.

and when you change the JDK from 8 to 17, you should change the **Javax packages** to **Jakarta packages**.

I guess this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your @Entity class is not from the correct package.  That is why the UserPreferences class is not recognized by JPA.

Please try:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table 
@Table(name = "USERS_PREFERENCES")
public class UserPreferences { ...
```